# How to publish a music file (mp3) on facebook

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I am developing an application which needs me to publish an audio file to facebook account. I am publishing it through FBStream and in the

```
NSString *str = @"{'media': [{
    'type': 'music', 
    'src': 'http://www.looptvandfilm.com/blog/Radiohead%20-%20In%20Rainbows/01%20-%20Radiohead%20-%2015%20Step.MP3', 
    'title': '15 Step', 
    'artist': 'Radiohead', 
    'album': 'In Rainbows'
}]}";

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: str, @"attachment" ,nil,@"message",nil];


    [[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.stream.publish" params:params];
```

I can publish/post my images and videos to facebook using same pattern, but when I try this code it show "type music is not supported". I got this string value from: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments.

Please help me to get out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post it, by using this string(str) format,

```
NSString *str = @"{'media': [{
    'type': 'mp3', 
    'src': 'http://www.looptvandfilm.com/blog/Radiohead%20-%20In%20Rainbows/01%20-%20Radiohead%20-%2015%20Step.MP3', 
    'title': '15 Step', 
    'artist': 'Radiohead', 
    'album': 'In Rainbows'
}]}";
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your code. Also try to give code for post specific user's wall if u tried ever. i would post a text message,links..

Comment: @AmitBattan Hi, I haven't tried it with Graph API. I think it's not available in Graph API but I am not sure. You can give it a try.